# How to insert new row to existing table which has relation with another table while stating relationship row that already inserted

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Consider there are two tables called `Parent`, `Child` and most importantly **they have relationship with each other**. There are already existing data in each table.

How to insert data automatically to each table generically and doesn't duplicates the row from another table which states the relationship with other table in Sqlalchemy. For example, I inserted `Father` row into `Parent` table and stated its relationship with `Child1` row in `Child` table, however once I try to insert `Mother` into `Parent` table and mother row also has relationship with same child row `Child1` in other `Session`, `Child1` is duplicated.

You can use this example code

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, create_engine, text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session
from sqlalchemy.orm.scoping import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:", 
                       echo=True)

Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                        autoflush=False,
                                        bind=engine))

# declarative base class
Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    surname = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)
    sex = Column(String)
    nationality = Column(Integer)

    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"id: {self.id} name: {self.name} surname: {self.surname} age: {self.age} sex: {self.sex} nationality: {self.nationality}"

# child class

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    surname = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)
    sex = Column(String)
    nationality = Column(Integer)

    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))

    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"id: {self.id} name: {self.name} surname: {self.surname} age: {self.age} sex: {self.sex} nationality: {self.nationality} parent_id: {self.parent_id}"



# create all configuration
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

child1 = Child(name = "child1_name",
               surname= "child1_name",
               age= 3,
               sex = "female",
               nationality = "solar_system")


parent1 = Parent(name = "father_name",
                surname = "father_surname",
                age = 275,
                sex = "male",
                nationality = "Martian",
                child = child1)

parent2 = Parent(name = "mother_name",
                surname = "mother_surname",
                age = 75,
                sex = "female",
                nationality = "Swiss",
                child = child1)


def insert_multi_data_to_db(data_collection:list):
    for data in data_collection:
        session.add(data)

        session.flush()
        session.commit()
    
        session.close()

# insert_multi_data_to_db(data_collection=[child1])
```

Edit: My sincere apologies to everyone. The code example above has tables which their relations are not correctly configured. I've updated them.

Comment: Problem is when uploading each row in different sessions, it duplicates the relationship row in its table.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is the relationship definition is backwards. You have the FK in `Parent` referencing `Child`.
This means a parent can have 0 or 1 children. Resulting in duplicate `Child` rows when attempting to create both mother and father.
Further, no child can have a sibling as creating one would duplicate the the parent(s).  Instead move your FK to the `Child` table.
Now a parent can have any number of children. Still you have to how to handle multiple parents. I see 2 options.

1. Create both a FK to mother  and a FK to father in the `Child` table.
2. Create a 3rd table `Parent_Child` with FK to both `Parent` and `Child` and a relationship type.  You can now have any number of relationships: Step Mother, Grand Father, Uncle, ... if desired.

Hint: Do not store age. It changes regularly for every row thus you need a process to update it; when do you run that process: annually (1-Jan, 31-Dec, some random day) or daily (which ones get updated). Instead store date-of-birth and derive the age in the query.  

I am not completely sure how to define this in SQLAlchemy, but, for #1 above should be something like:  (See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7982964e9c2d1c31be16ee9cd543240e) for example with Postgres construction)

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    surname = Column(String)
    age = Column(Date)
    sex = Column(String)
    nationality = Column(Integer)

    
    def __repr__(self):
        return ???


# child class

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    surname = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)
    sex = Column(String)
    nationality = Column(Integer)
    mother_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    father_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))    
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return ???
```

Challenge: Notice the attributes on `Parent` and 'Child`. Except for defining the foreign keys they are identical. As is proper since both are persons. What happens when the child grows up and becomes a parent. You now have duplicates (2 rows to define 1 person). So combine` Parent`and`Child` into a single table.  

I realize this is probably a homework assignment and you may not be able to change what is stored (age vs. dob) or the basic table structure. But working well with SQL is as much a *way of thinking* as it is following some coding conventions. Never too early to start making that change.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is calling the relationship row from the existing database. For example using this code can be helpful,

```
Session\
       .query(Parent)\
       .filter(Parent.name == "father_name")\
       .first()
```